# How to display all the split array in Single Alert without comma separator

Tags: javascript, html, web

I Splitted the Url string into n number , now i want it to be displayed in single alert or some better modular way without the comma separation

My String can carry n number of error so there can be split array of n number

It should show Like with OL list,WITHOUT ANY COMMA SEPARATOR

1. ID cannot be Null
2. Please check character (Break the line)
3. And So on

My code is below

```
   var qtr="http://google.sd.asp?err=ID%20cannot%20be%20NULL/Zero.%0A%0D%20Id%20is%20not%20numeric%20-%202B.%20%0A%0D%20Company%20name%20for%20the%20id%20-%203%20is%20more%20than%20255%20characters.%20";

    var uesp= unescape(qtr);

    var splitqtr = uesp.split('?err=')[1].split('.');
alert(splitqtr);

for(i=0;i<splitqtr .length;i++)
{


alert(splitqtr[i]);

}
```

Comment: So, you're splitting but then you want to join them back together again? Why not just output the unsplit version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the number to each string, then join them with line breaks:

```
for (i = 0; i < splitqtr.length; i++) {
  splitqtr[i] = (i + 1) + ". " + splitqtr[i];
}
alert(splitqtr.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine the array values to a single string without using the comma as a separator, you can use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with any argument. You may want to use the empty string:

```
> splitqtr.join("")
"ID cannot be NULL/Zero\n\r Id is not numeric - 2B \n\r Company name for the id - 3 is more than 255 characters "
```

To show them as a numbered list, you will need to add the number before each; I also trimmed the strings:

```
for (var i=1; i<=splitqtr.length; i++)
    splitqtr[i] = i". "+splitqtr[i].trim();
```

Then join them with a linebreak:

```
> splitqtr.join("\n")
"1. ID cannot be NULL/Zero\n2. Id is not numeric - 2B\n3. Company name for the id - 3 is more than 255 characters\n4. "
```

Comment: Note: The trim method only exist in recent browsers, for example not in IE 8. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: I know, but it seems to be needed in here. The site you linked offers a simple shim for old browsers.